# Jssor Slider doesn't start

Tags: jssor

Here is the link to the page where I have pasted the script www.multi-head.pl

Aboe the shoutbox you can see a big banner 1172px wide that I would like to animate with others that are in the code. The thing is that the slider is displaying the images but they dont want to start.

```
<center>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-no-jquery.html
        //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    }
</script>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 1171px;
    height: 257px;">

    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1171px; height: 257px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
            <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/bit2sk.png" />         
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/a1s1t0.png"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2nsxbnk.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">content slider</a>
    <!-- Trigger -->
    <script>
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    </script>
</div>
```

This is how I pasted the code inside?

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://multi-head.pl/public/js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
```